# awk to count lines in column of file

Tags: awk, count

I have a large file that I want to use `awk` to count the lines in a specific column `$5`, before the`:` and only count `-uniq` entries, but seem to be having trouble getting the syntax correct.  Thank you :).

**Sample Input**

```
chr1    955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 1   0
chr1    955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 2   0
chr1    955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 3   0
chr1    955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 4   1
chr1    955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 5   1

awk -F: ' NR > 1 { count += $5 } -uniq' Input
```

**Desired output**

```
1
```

Comment: Is your desired output `1` because there is only `AGRN` in your example?

Comment: Would you mind more clearly rewriting your desired logic?  I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Also, is it absolutely necessary to use only awk?

Comment: No it is not necessary to use `awk`, the desired out is 1 because eventhough there are 5 lines with `AGRN` in it, `AGRN` is only unique 1 time.  Thank you :).

Comment: Does it have to be awk?  What about `cut -f5 Input | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l`

Comment: @Hambone `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq` is better

Comment: I thought `awk -F'[ \t]+|:' '{print $6}' Input | sort -u | wc -l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ \t:]+' '{a[$5]=1;} END{for (k in a)n++; print n;}' Input
1
```

- `-F'[ \t:]+'`

  This tells awk to use spaces, tabs, or colons as the field separator.
- `a[$5]=1`

  As we loop through each line, this adds an entry into associative array `a` for each value of `$5` encountered.
- `END{for (k in a)n++; print n;}`

  After we have finished reading the file, this counts the number of keys in associative array `a` and prints the total.

Comment: Would this theoretically fail if one of the first four fields contained a colon?

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic, portable awk approach:

```
$ awk '{sub(/:.*/,"",$5)} !seen[$5]++{unq++} END{print unq}' file
1
```

The briefer but gawk-only (courtesy of `length(array)`) approach:

```
$ awk '{seen[$5]} END{print length(seen)}' file
1
```